# Nexus 3.0.0-03 startup on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, nexus, sonatype

After installing nexus-3.0.0-03 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (no X) I have the following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:270)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.util.ArgumentStack.popString(ArgumentStack.java:14)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:37)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Button.<init>(Button.java:152)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.util.MessageBox.addChoice(MessageBox.java:151)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.util.MessageBox.addChoice(MessageBox.java:163)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.ErrorHandler.displayGuiErrorMessage(ErrorHandler.java:14)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.ErrorHandler.reportError(ErrorHandler.java:22)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:71)
```

Command I use for starting the service is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre -Dexe4j.moduleName=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus -Dinstall4j.launcherId=245 -Dinstall4j.swt=false -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Di4jv=0 -Xms256M -Xmx768M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dkaraf.home=. -Dkaraf.base=. -Dkaraf.etc=etc -Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/java.util.logging.properties -Dkaraf.data=data -Dkaraf.instances=data/instances -Djava.io.tmpdir=data/tmp -Dkaraf.startLocalConsole=false -Di4j.vpt=true -classpath /opt/nexus/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:/opt/nexus/lib/karaf.jar:/opt/nexus/lib/karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:/opt/nexus/lib/karaf-jmx-boot.jar:/opt/nexus/lib/karaf-jaas-boot.jar:/opt/nexus/lib/karaf-nexus-branding.jar com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher run 9d17dc87 org.apache.karaf.main.Main
```

Can you configure Nexus not to use X11? Would be grateful for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**

When starting Nexus using:

```
./nexus run
```

it is started properly, but it does not run as a service then.

Answer (score 0):

X11 is not required, but Nexus 3 does use install4j as it's launcher, and in some error conditions it unfortunately may try to pop up a dialog (this can be seen from the stack trace).

Check the logs to see if there is more information.  Also curious, from your description it seems like you may not be using the bin/nexus script?  You should be using that.  See here: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#service-linux

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the question there is full stack trace that is printed during start.
In the command (retrieved from systemctl start nexus command) there is part that uses bin/nexus:
-Dexe4j.moduleName=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus
Updated my question.